# Using custom URL for httptest.NewServer in Go

Tags: unit-testing, http, go

I am running UT on some rest calls by creating a http test server in the Go language. My code is as follows.

```
type student struct{
FirstName string
LastName string
}

func testGetStudentName() {
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response = new(student)
    response.FirstName = "Some"
    response.LastName = "Name"
    b, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err == nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, string(b[:]))
        }
    }))
    defer ts.Close()
    student1 := base.getStudent("123")
    log.Print("testServerUrl",testServer.URL) //prints out http://127.0.0.1:49931 ( port changes every time this is run)

   ts.URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8099" //this assignment does not quite change the URL of the created test server.
}
```

In the file being tested,

```
var baseURL = "http://originalUrl.com"
var mockUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:49855"
func Init(mockServer bool){
    if mockServer {
        baseURL = mockUrl
    }
}

func getStudent(id String){
     url := baseUrl + "/student/" + id
     req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
}
```

This init is called from my test.

This creates a new test server and runs the calls on a random port. Is it possible for me to run this server on a port I specify?

Comment: I have multiple api's that I test and in those functions, I append the path to the base URL. 
In my original function, I have a base URL like "http://someserver.com"

Under getStudent() I modify that to be baseUrl + "/student/{id}"
Under getClass() I would change to baseUrl + "/class/{id}"

Because each of the httptest server I create having different ports I get 127.0.0.1:49855/student/1: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: I hope my edit makes more sense.. I am trying to explain it the best I could. In the file that I am testing, I have an Init that is called by test to modify the base URL
Like,
var baseURL = "http://originalUrl.com"
var mockUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:49855"
func Init(mockServer bool){
if mockServer {
  baseURL = mockUrl
 }
}

Comment: Because I am appending the URL in each of the api calls, it would still fail. 
Just like I append some value to url in the getStudent function, I would do in getClass function too. Basically the URL is changed inside the functions. With a custom URL/port, I can specify the final URL in the testServer

Comment: That is what I did.. Thank you. Even though this works, I would like to know if we can use custom ports for httptest. Is that possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most applications use the port assigned in NewServer or NewUnstartedServer because this port will not conflict with a port in use on the machine. Instead of assigning a port, they set the base URL for the service to the [test server's URL](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server.URL).

If you do want to set the listening port, do the following:

```
// create a listener with the desired port.
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

ts := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(handler)

// NewUnstartedServer creates a listener. Close that listener and replace 
// with the one we created.
ts.Listener.Close()
ts.Listener = l

// Start the server.
ts.Start()
// Stop the server on return from the function.  
defer ts.Close()

// Add your test code here.
```

Comment: After `ts.Start()`, you can write `defer ts.Close()` and after that start writing your tests.

Comment: I tried to do this but it actually never worked out for me. Taking the `httptest` server URL and passing it to my HTTP client did it though.